# Blow up algebras

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, blowup

Consider a ring $R$, an ideal $I$ in $R$ (with generators $g_1,\ldots,g_n$). Then for some $f\in I$ the map $R\rightarrow R[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/(fx_1-g_1,\ldots,fx_n-g_n)$ should correspond to blowing up $\text{Spec}(R)$ along $I$. If I take $R=k[a,b]$ the affine plane, $I=(a,b)$, $f=a$ then I get $k[a,b][x,y]/(a x-a,ax-y)=k[a,b,x]/(ax-a)$. Shouldn't this be a polynomial ring in two variables? Geometrically the Spec is an affine chart in the blow up.

Comment: Your first statement is not true. The exceptional divisor of blowing up the plan along the origin is a copy of $\mathbb{P}^1$, and hence the entire blowup is not affine. Furthermore, one typically defines the blowup as being the zariski closure of the preimage of the open subset defined by removing the closed subscheme defined by $I$, whereas your definition is more like taking the entire preimage.

Comment: @RghtHndSd I agree that the blow up is not affine, but I think it should be an affine chart?

Comment: @eyial667 please use `$\operatorname{Spec}$` to improve the formatting of Spec in the future - it produces better spacing.